# Word for "the people who lose in a battlefield"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Example:

> The dog carcasses were scattered everywhere. They looked like the
>   [...] of a battlefield.

The closest word I can think of is "loser" but I think it doesn't quite make it.

Any suggestion?

Comment: How about simply "It looked like a battlefield"?

Comment: Title is a bit deceptive, you really meant: "Those who died in battle"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about ***["casualties"](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/casualty)***

> A person killed or injured in a war or accident:

Answer (score 6):

slain or fallen , on or from could be better than of.

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible ways in which you could modify the wording of the second sentence so as to enable you to use a greater range of idiomatic terms:

One is to use 'battlefield' attributively:

> They looked like battlefield {victims / casualties}.

The other is to use **on a battlefield** rather than **of a battlefield**:

> They looked like {corpses / casualties / the fallen / the slain / the dead / the wounded} on a battlefield.

Answer (score 0):

[Victim](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/victim): ( from TFD)

> - a person or thing that suffers harm, death, etc, from another or from some adverse act, circumstance. Victims of war.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the broader context, why not use something more idiomatic?

> *the remains of war*

or

> *the war dead*

Comment: ... aftermath. (Many kids used to look like dead dogs after math.)

Answer (score 0):

“Casualties” is the word I would use if you want to emphasize that they were killed/injured; otherwise, I think “loser” *is* the word you are looking for. (Cf. http://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/winner, antonyms of sense 2).  Rephrasing, e.g. “they looked like they had lost a battle here” might sound better.

Comment: As you've edited, I have now removed my previous comment.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Some possibilities:

- [defeated](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/defeated?searchDictCode=all) *having been beaten in a battle or other contest*
- [vanquished](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/vanquished) *defeated*
- [slain](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/slain?s=t) *past participle of slay: to kill by violence; to destroy; extinguish.*
- [corpses](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/corpse?q=corpses&searchDictCode=all) *dead bodies, especially of human beings rather than animals.*
- [fallen](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/fallen) *killed in battle with glory*

<sub>The links are to random dictionaries.</sub>

Comment: Is this supposed to be a sentence? Or just a list of words? There’s no punctuation, no context, no explanations of what the words mean or how they differ, no references to their use—nothing. Definite -1.

Comment: This answer does not explain itself very well, however it brings up the word I first thought of; _Defeated_. _Vanquished_ is also an excellent pick. +1, but please edit to define those two.

Comment: When I think of vanquished why do I think of LOTR and Gandalf on the bridge of Khazard Dum with the Balrog? Vanquished seems more like a word used to describe the out come of a battle: "The foe was vanquished, but our fallen were great"

Answer (score 0):

Vestiges comes to mind. The implication is that there was a conflict that no one walked away from.

Comment: First off, welcome to English.se. Could you flesh this out a bit? I do think vestiges is somewhat relevant to what is left after a battle... but your answer could be much clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your audience and intent, something like "detritus" might work.

> *noun* - [dih-**trahy**-t*uh* s]
>
> 1. rock in small particles or other material worn or broken away from a mass, as by the action of water or glacial ice.
> 2. any [disintegrated](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/disintegrated) material; debris.

*via [dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/detritus)*

Comment: Please only supply phonetic transcriptions using the standard [International Phonetic Alphabet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet), so that everyone around the world can understand them.

Comment: I think this word would work better for battlefield equipment than for the soldiers themselves.

Answer (score 0):

the residue of war on a battlefield.

Otherwise, I like 'slain'  or 'fallen'.